# Jquery closest() and match() won't work

Tags: jquery, html

I've setup a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/zatHH/422/

I am trying to hide the parent div if an `<a>` contains 'no phrase found'.

Sadly , what I wrote in there won't work and if anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `match` incorrectly as it expects a regular expression, plus you're attempting to use it on a jQuery object. Regardless, jQuery has `:contains` which will suit your needs:

```
 $('#cd_category_0 li a:contains("No phrase found by")').closest('.cd-extendable').hide();
```

```js
$('#cd_category_0 li a:contains("No phrase found by")').closest('.cd-extendable').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-extendable opened">
    <div class="dropdown">All Categories</div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="bc" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="uls">
            <ul id="cd_category_0">
                <li accesskey="" class="selected"><a href="javascript://">All Categories</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
                <li accesskey=""><span title="Show Subcategories"></span><a href="javascript://">No phrase found by
                    "pages+name+lt_" key</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use :contains() instead it should give you the output you are looking for.

```
    $("#cd_category_0 li a:contains('No phrase found by')").closest('.cd-extendable').hide();
```